# Disable password access through SSH?

Tags: security, ssh, password, remote-access

I'm setting up a server for backing up my desktop box remotely. I want to prevent remote password access to the server, permitting only users with private keys (AKA my desktop box) to access it. How can I block remote password access while allowing physical password access to the server?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just insert the following to the sshd config on the server (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

You might need to reload the ssh service

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

That should do the trick ;)

For more options type `man sshd_config` in to your terminal.

Comment: See this thread for more hints: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server

Comment: do i need to restart ssh after that?

Comment: Of course, you must.

Answer (score 26):

Just a note about SSH access to servers - you may also want to disable the root user from ssh, [this way](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/) at least hackers will have to guess the username as well.

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Comment: Or just lock and delete the password for the root account. (Assuming the default user has sudo access)