# Easiest way to copy ssh keys to another machine?

Tags: ssh

I am lazy at home and use password authentication for my home machines. I am ready to move to key based authentication. There are many options on the web on how to do this, including catting then sshing the key over, scping the key over directly, etc.

I am looking for the easiest and recommended way to copy a key over, hopefully there is a convenience wrapper somewhere in the Ubuntu ssh package?

I'm already aware on [how to shut off password logins](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1991/disable-password-access-through-ssh).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307881/ssh-public-key-authentication-doesnt-work/848174#answer-848174

Answer (score 622, accepted):

The `ssh-copy-id` command (in the **openssh-client** package and installed by default) does exactly this:

```
ssh-copy-id user@hostname.example.com
```

copies the public key of your default identity (use `-i identity_file` for other identities) to the remote host.

The default identity is your "standard" ssh key. It consists of two files (public and private key) in your `~/.ssh` directory, normally named `identity`, `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa` or `id_ed25519` (and the same with `.pub`), depending on the type of key. If you did not create more than one ssh key, you do not have to worry about specifying the identity, ssh-copy-id will just pick it automatically.

In case you do not have an identity, you can generate one with the tool `ssh-keygen`.

In addition, if the server uses a port different from the default one (`22`) you should use quotation marks in this way ([source](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=99785)):

```
ssh-copy-id "user@hostname.example.com -p <port-number>"
```

Comment: What is the default identity?

Comment: @Oxwivi: The default identity is your "standard" ssh key. It consists of two files (public and private key) in your `~/.ssh` directory, normally named ``identity`, `id_rsa` or `id_dsa` (and the same with `.pub`), depending on the type of key. If you did not create more than one ssh key, you do not have to worry about specifying the file, `ssh-copy-id` will just pick it automatically.

Comment: for different port use this: `ssh-copy-id "user@host -p 6842"`

Comment: What if the remote server you're copying to doesn't allow password prompts and is basically locked down save for SSH access?

Comment: On mac you can do `brew install ssh-copy-id` and then run the command.

Comment: I have the ssh-key-agent running and this command pushed ALL of my keys in the agent to the remote server and not only the default key in my .ssh profile folder. The `-i` Option is important if you use the agent.

Comment: @MarcelStimberg please update answer to include -i profile ; people likely have more than 1 key and push them all, or have to hunt for the -i option in comments

Comment: my machine (a real time linux distribution) do not have it installed. It has only `opkg` manager. How can i install it? `opkg install sshopen` says it is up to date......

Answer (score 171):

I like the answer from Marcel. I did not know this command. I've always been using what I had found on the [Oracle web site](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/sshuser-33/index.html):

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<hostname> 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys && echo "Key copied"'
```

I thought to post it here still, because it is a good illustration of what can be achieved in *shell code* with the power of `ssh`. But using the `ssh-copy-id` is definitively a safer way to do it properly!

Note that if the folder `.ssh` does not already exist, the above command will fail. In addition, it might be better when creating the file to set a minimum possible permission (basically read-write for owner only). Here is a more advanced command:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<hostname> 'umask 0077; mkdir -p .ssh; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys && echo "Key copied"'
```

Comment: This exact commands also work from a Mac too

Comment: It should work under any Unix with most shell. I've update the post with an updated command in case the folder `.ssh` does not exist on the remote side.

Comment: The `cat` is not necessary - a normal input redirection is enough, e.g. `< ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh ...`

Comment: @Huygens Thanks. More useful to remember this one, because you do not need to install anything and it can also be good for executing foreign commands e.g. changing server-side permissions as you demonstrated in your advanced example.

Comment: I much prefer this way since it lets you use verbose ssh which is helpful in figuring out why things are broken. sshcopyid just froze and never worked, this went perfectly.

Comment: I would shorten your last command: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<hostname>
 'mkdir .ssh; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`. No need for the the p (parent) flag in mkdir. Never used the umask and echo key copied does not help. A detail: if you know that you will be the first entry in the authorized_keys, a **>** (wipe the file and insert the content) is fine.

Comment: I use the following approach in peace `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_name.pub |  ssh <username>@192.168.1.X 
"mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` - it for my old mac - `El Capitan`

Answer (score 32):

### Graphical method

1. Open **Applications** ▸ **Passwords and Keys** ▸ **My Personal Keys**.
2. Select your key and then click **Remote** ▸ **Configure Key for Secure Shell**.

[image: Set Up Computer for SSH Connection]

Comment: I don't have "Passwords and Encryption Keys" in my menu.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using? In Ubuntu 10.04 LTS this should be available by default.

Comment: 10.10, just added the tag. Marcel's answer is what I'm looking for, though +1 for your desktop oriented answer!

Comment: This program is `seahorse`.

Comment: I think this application is in the System->Preferences menu in 10.10 (can't check it right now, I'm on 10.04)

Comment: Why a GUI when there is the terminal and at least **four** different methods for that to make use of?

Answer (score 20):

On Ubuntu you can fetch your keys from Launchpad:

```
ssh-import-id [launchpad account name]
```

**Details**:

1. You need a Launchpad account so [login or create an account](https://launchpad.net/+login)
2. After logging in, click the button next to *SSH keys:*
3. Paste the contents of your public key file in that field (including comment). Such a key looks like:

   ```
   ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza .... UyDOFDqJp lekensteyn
   ```

   Here, `ssh-rsa` indicates that the key is a RSA key, `AAAAB3Nza .... UyDOFDqJp` is the actual key and `lekensteyn` is the comment.
4. Save the key by pressing *Import Public Key*
5. If everything went well, your key should now be listed under *SSH keys:*

The package `ssh-import-id` needs to be installed on the machine which needs to be accessed from remote. This package is installed together with the `openssh-server` package as it's a recommended package for `openssh-server`. After making sure that `ssh-import-id` has been installed On the client machine, run:

```
ssh-import-id [launchpad account name]
```

This will download the public key from the Launchpad servers over HTTPS which protects you from MITM attacks.

On Ubuntu Lucid and before, you can accomplish the same with:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~[lp acount name]/+sshkeys -O - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && echo >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The `echo` command is needed to get an extra newline after the line with the SSH key.

- [Manual page of ssh-import-id](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/ssh-import-id.1.html)

Answer (score 17):

for custom port

```
ssh-copy-id -i "user@hostname.example.com -p2222"
```

-i switch defaults to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, if you want another key, put the path of the key after -i

**WARNING:** If you did not write the -i it will copy all your keys found in ~/.ssh

Comment: Are you sure about that WARNING? "-i identity_file - Use only the key(s) contained in identity_file (rather than looking for identities via ssh-add(1) or in the default_ID_file). If the filename does not end in .pub this is added.  If the filename is omitted, the default_ID_file is used."

Answer (score 15):

Here is a less secure, but very simple solution(not recommended for servers):

Move `~/.ssh` to the new machine and run `ssh-add`. DONE!

LONG ANSWER:

1. In the old machine, take the folder `~/.ssh` to an USB drive, or to any other storage you like.
2. On the new machine, put the folder under `~` aka `/home/$USER`.
3. Run `ssh-add`, on the new machine done.

Comment: Important to add, make sure to restore permissions on files, sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
and on folder, if whole folder was copied
sudo chmod 755 ~/.ssh

Comment: You definitely don't want to do it this way. By doing this you're not only copying your public key, but your private key as well! This is especially dangerous when the other machine is shared with other users that have root privileges. They'll have access to your private key!

Comment: Pls update  your post - your solution IS GOOD to copy ssh keys for your another work machine (for example from desktop to laptop) but bad idea to do it for alive host\server (that's why other answers "over-complicated"). And thank you for your answer - it worked for me too.

Answer (score 5):

`ssh-copy-id` does exactly that.  I am not sure why some of the other answers here add inaccurate information.  The help shows the following:

```
~$ ssh-copy-id -h
Usage: /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id [-h|-?|-f|-n] [-i [identity_file]] [-p port] [[-o <ssh -o options>] ...] [user@]hostname
    -f: force mode -- copy keys without trying to check if they are already installed
    -n: dry run    -- no keys are actually copied
    -h|-?: print this help
```

I just tried the following on Ubuntu 18.04 client with a CentOS 7.6 server and it worked like a charm.  The example shows using a custom port of `2222`, and specifying a public key at `~/.ssh/path-to-rsa.pub`

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/path-to-rsa.pub -p 2222 myusername@hostname.tld
```

Before running the command, I actually used the `-n` switch at the end to do a dry run which confirmed that the command will work as intended.  Once I confirmed it I ran the command again as above, without the `-n` switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a host key like in the case of AWS EC2, then do this

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -i hostkey.pem hostname@hostaddress 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys && echo "Key copied" '
```

Next time, simply do this:

```
ssh hostname@hostaddress
```