# Is it possible to save ssh password in remmina?

Tags: ssh, remmina

I have remmina 0.9.99.1 (1.0.0) in ubuntu precise 12.04

Can I save the ssh password so that it won't prompt me again for it

Comment: using the ssh-agent should work; `ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_key`; have a look look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61557/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-authentication-keys and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine. HTH

Answer (score 6):

This might help [how to save passwords in remmina](http://technologyflirt.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-save-ssh-password-in-remmina.html)

1. Go to dash type 'passwords' and click password and keys.
2. We need to create a new key for ssh logins, so select 'Secure Shell Key'
3. Type in any name for your ssh key.
4. Type in a new pass-phrase for the key, this can be anything string or even empty which is not recommended of course.
5. Now that the ssh key-ring is setup, we can save the credentials for our desired ssh servers. Just right click the newly created key ring
6. Enter the hostname or ip for the desired ssh server, user id.
7. Now it asks for the ssh password the server.
   That does it, now you can ssh the server using console without entering the password. Now you can save as many credentials as you like by repeating steps 5 to 7.

Comment: How do I delete a key for an added server (revert this)?