# Which files to copy in order to get the same SSH key login on 2 servers?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, login

I have a server that I log in with SSH and I use key based authentication. I now set up a second server and I want to use the same key for login.

Thus, I copied the file `~/.ssh/authorized_key` from the old server to the new server.

On the Windows client, I cloned the SSH configuration in Putty and only exchanged the IP address of the server.

This does not seem to be sufficient. The error message of Putty on Windows is

> PuTTY Fatal Error
>
> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

And on the SSH console I see

> Server refused our key

The server configuration is

```
AllowGroups sshlogin
Port 2233
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Even if I copy the other key files (`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`), I still can't login.

```
# ls -l
total 12
-rw------- 1 root root  411 Jan 14 22:39 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 root root 1792 Jan 14 22:53 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 root root  411 Jan 14 22:39 id_rsa.pub
```

Which files do I need to copy to get an identical SSH login on both machines?

---

I have tried:

- [Can't make a 2nd ssh key login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377718/cant-make-a-2nd-ssh-key-login?rq=1), but it's about 2 different keys on 1 server. I need 1 identical key on 2 servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a permission problem:

```
-rw------- 1 root root  411 Jan 14 22:39 authorized_keys
```

should not be accessible by `root:root` but by the user who shall log in. So the following fixed the issue:

```
chown myuser:myuser authorized_keys
rm id_rsa
rm id_rsa.pub
service sshd restart
```

Comment: also, the parent directory (normally /home/USER) may only be writetable for the owner (755).

Comment: In the future use `ssh-copy-id` , it copies your public key (rsa.pub) to the server (~/.ssh/authorized_keys) and sets proper permissions.

Comment: @Panther: thanks for the hint. So I upload `rsa.pub`, then use `ssh-copy-id` and then delete `rsa.pub`? I don't think the tool can copy something to the server, because the source is my KeePass file on Windows, where `ssh-copy-id` does not have access to.

Comment: From the client you run `ssh-copy-id user@server ` and everything is taken care of for you. You can keep or delete the rsa.pub on the client, but I usually keep it. You need the rsa to log in with.

Comment: @Panther: there's [no such tool on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/224810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ssh-copy-id-for-windows), so I would need to replicate its behavior. Basically that's what I did (without knowing it)

Comment: windows with what tool? PuTTY ? You can see https://serverfault.com/questions/224810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ssh-copy-id-for-windows , or perhaps WSL