# Backup, sync, and mirror application

Tags: backup, sync, rsync, mirrors

On Windows I used [Zback](http://titan.fsb.hr/~dzorc/zback.html) for:

- Backing up some directories to a networked drive.

  (i.e, copying all new files from source to target)
- Keeping a mirror of some directories on a networked drive.

  (i.e, copying all new files from source to target, and deleting files from target which no longer exist on source)
- Syncing my working folder to my flash drive.

  (i.e., overwriting older files on target with newer files from source, and vice versa)

Is there any single application for Ubuntu that can do all this?

Preferably something with scripting and GUI support. I really don't want to have to resort to Wine for something so simple. I tried `grsync`, but this seems lacking in functionality.

Do I have to go learn `rsync`, or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use rsync its extremely powerful, very generic and not that hard to use really.

- **Your backup scenario:**

  ```
  rsync -avz  /home/myfolder/* 192.168.40.1:/remote/backup/myfolder/*
  ```
- **Keeping folders in sync (removing extroneous stuff from destination)**

  ```
  rsync -avz  --delete  /home/keepsynced 192.168.40.1:/remote/backup/keepsynced
  ```
- **From folder to usb:**

  Just like the first one just change IP , to a local path instead.
  Rsync will overwrite files on the remote end if they exist.

If you want to skip entering a password every time are syncing to your network backup host. Just follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine) instruction

Comment: notice the difference between ending a path with / , or just the name of the folder. Using / will take the files within that folder while ending just with the folder name, will rsync that folder

Comment: You might also want to use snapshot like backups instead of just making an up to date copy of files. Much like apples time machine. check out rsnapshot