# Simplest way to set up new user with SSH access on remote host, given root access

Tags: ssh, user-management, adduser, ceph, cloud-init

I am writing a tutorial on setting up Ceph the hard way, shell all the way.

I am not happy with the number of ssh commands it takes to connect to a remote host as root, create new user, then scp keys over... there must be a smarter, simpler way - especially on Ubuntu.

Here is the exact problem:
local user FOO that has access to remote server with user ROOT needs to setup keys (and possibly the user as well) for user CEPH. Repeat n times with n remote hosts.

Any clever one-liners I am missing?

**current steps:**

```
scp -i digitalocean id_rsa.pub storage-1:/root
ssh -i digitalocean storage-1
useradd ceph
mkdir ~ceph/.ssh
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~ceph/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~ceph/.ssh
chmod 600 ~ceph/.ssh/authorized_keys 
chown ceph:ceph ~ceph/.ssh/authorized_keys 
chown ceph:ceph ~ceph/.ssh/
rm id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing all that in one SSH command? Or saving all that to a script, scp'ing that to the server (one command) and launching it with ssh (second command)? What commands do you run atm?

Comment: Since it is a tutorial, I would still have to have the user read, type-up the script, which is a sequence of mkdir/chown/chmod/scp/chown/chmod. I can detail the actual steps once I am back home.

Comment: You could edit your question, you know.

Comment: ssh-copy-id looks promising, after the user is setup. http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is Digital Ocean, the problem can be addressed by setting userdata as part of the initial cloud instance bootup - the following will create a ceph user, put it in the sudoers group, and configure the SSH keys required to provide log in.

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: ceph
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDf0q4PyG0doiBQYV7OlOxbRjle026hJPBWD+eKHWuVXIpAiQlSElEBqQn0pOqNJZ3IBCvSLnrdZTUph4czNC4885AArS9NkyM7lK27Oo8RV888jWc8hsx4CD2uNfkuHL+NI5xPB/QT3Um2Zi7GRkIwIgNPN5uqUtXvjgA+i1CS0Ku4ld8vndXvr504jV9BMQoZrXEST3YlriOb8Wf7hYqphVMpF3b+8df96Pxsj0+iZqayS9wFcL8ITPApHi0yVwS8TjxEtI3FDpCbf7Y/DmTGOv49+AWBkFhS2ZwwGTX65L61PDlTSAzL+rPFmHaQBHnsli8U9N6E4XHDEOjbSMRX f2@digitalocean
```

I still believe there should be a smart way to do this not involving the cloud fabric.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your problem lies in the creation of `.ssh`. What I'd do use use `ssh-keygen`, which will create it if doesn't exist and set permissions properly (and, of course, create a key pair for the user).

```
$ scp -i digitalocean id_rsa.pub storage-1:/tmp
$ ssh digitalocean storage-1 '
adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password  ceph
echo | sudo -u ceph ssh-keygen  -N "" -f ~ceph/.ssh/id_rsa 
sudo -u cp /tmp/id_rsa.pub ~ceph/.ssh/authorized_keys
'
```

Notes:

- use `adduser` instead of `useradd` - it creates a skeleton home directory, from `/etc/skel`.
- `--gecos ""` and `--disabled-password` are used to avoid prompting. If you don't mind prompts for name and password, you skip these options.
- `ssh-keygen` can create `.ssh` with the right permissions
- Again, `-N ""` and `-f ~ceph/.ssh/id_rsa` are used to avoid prompts. You can skip these if you don't mind prompts for the key location (for which the default is fine) and if you wish to set a passphrase.
- Neither `.ssh` nor `.ssh/authorized_keys` *need* to have `700` as the mode. As long as only the owner can write to them, it's fine (`755` for `.ssh` and `644` for `.ssh/authorized_keys` is just fine).

Answer (score 0):

I found a more generic solution by modifying the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine) to accomplish this while logging in as another user:

```
 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@storage-1 'useradd ceph; umask 0077; mkdir -p ~ceph/.ssh; cat >> ~ceph/.ssh/authorized_keys && echo "Key copied"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ssh-copy-id` to transfer your SSH key to a remote host.

#### Example:

```
mallard@steamroller:~$ ssh-copy-id mallard@puter
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'mallard@puter'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

It automatically creates directories (such as `.ssh`) and sets them to the correct permissions.

Comment: Yep. The issue in this case is that the user on the target machine that the key needs adding to is not there yet... found a one-line solution modifying someone else's clever shell-fu with a nice stdout redirect, below.