# New computer, best way to add new ssh keys

Tags: ssh

I just got a new computer and I connect to 3 different remote machines using ssh. They all have logging in with password turned off so I have to have a key. What is the best way to copy my newly generated key to these machines without having to take down my walls?

Comment: What walls are those?

Comment: I am assuming you no longer have the system with the old key on it?  If you did it would be a simple matter of logging in from that to add your new public key to those hosts.  If you don't, then I think you're out of luck.  You'd have to get physical/console access to those remote machines some other way.

Comment: I do have access to that computer, just don’t have a full understanding of how those keys are stored. I think the answer below is getting at your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to copy ssh keys to another machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your OS, you can try:

```
ssh-copy-id username@host
```

To specify the key file use:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@host
```

You may have to copy your public key to a computer that already has SSH access to the three machines, otherwise these commands won't work without asking for a password.

I find this is much easier than using my old method:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@host 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: Awesome, I think this is what I was looking for. This was my initial thought but I wasn’t sure exactly how it would work. So copy my id_rsa.pub to my old computer and then copy that same file to the new computer? Are all public keys stored in one file? Or will I have to make sure I select the right one?