# ssh authentication server does not work

Tags: networking, server, ssh, password, authentication

i recently wanted to use ssh-keys instead of passwords for my server (Debian stretch). I am using an ubuntu subsystem on Windows (in case it matters).

I was following the top answer from this thread:
[Easiest way to copy ssh keys to another machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine)

I did the following:

1. Created a key with `ssh-keygen` and saved them at `.ssh/xxx.pub`
2. `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/xxx.pub user@server.tld`

After this step I got the following message:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: ".ssh/xxx.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@tserver.tld's password:

Number of key(s) added: 1
```

I even checked on the server under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` there is the key.

But still when I try to connect to the server via:

```
ssh root@server.tld
```

I have to login with password.

Has someone an idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i had to specify the key i want to use with '-i'

e.g.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@foo.bar
```

EDIT: You can also add a config file at `~/.ssh/config` and add the following code

`host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey`

then you don't have to use the `-i ...` parameter

Comment: Well, the default private key is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. (There are other "default" filenames, depending on the algorithm used, but `id_rsa` is very common.) What's your key's filename?

Comment: My key name was identity.pub, but i found the proper solution:

You can add a config file in ~/.ssh/config and do

host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey

thanks tho

Comment: `.ssh/config` would have been my next suggestion but I wonder why `identity.pub` isn't found automatically. It's one of the default files. Although it's more _"ssh-v1"_-ey (I guess).