# Certificate logins to servers

Tags: ssh, security, login, certificates

I have some ubuntu cloud servers running and has the iptable rules applied on them to allow only few ip addresses to connect via ssh. I know how to generate SSH-key for connecting to server with/without passphrase. My manager is asking if there is any some sort of certification login which allows to connect to the cloud computers which doesn't require changing iptable rules everytime. Does anyone know this with SSH or with something?. Please let me know...

Comment: I don't understand - if iptables only allows certain addresses, then only those addresses can connect. If you want to be able to constantly connect to the server with other machines, then you'd need to drop the iptables idea (IMO, I'm no expert).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [disable password-based login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1991/disable-password-access-through-ssh) on the ssh server and remove the iptables rules. Nobody will then be able to brute-force a password-login because it's disabled, but trusted users with their key-pairs would be able to login from everywhere.

To limit the usage of the keys, you can specify which hosts they can be used from with the `from` parameter in front of the key in `authorized_keys`, for instance:

```
from="255.255.255.255" ssh-rsa ASDFqwerty[...]
```

Comment: Moreover, it wouldn't have any problem removing ipables rules if I have set only for SSH, but i'm blocking many ports and also allowing some ports other than ssh.

Comment: Then leave the current ruleset in place, but create a rule that accepts the ssh-connections before the other rules.

Comment: I didn't get yoy exactly. Then in that case if a new user wants to access should I again change the iptables rules to allow ssh for the new user's ip?

Comment: Change the rules to allow ssh access from any IP.

Comment: The ssh server listens on port 22 and will take logins for any user. Opening port 22 tcp will let all requests get to the ssh server. Then the ssh server will decide if you can login based on what ssh keys are authorized and (if you do the from= thing) where the connection is coming from. tl;dr : Opening tcp port 22 will be all the iptables config you need. When you want to add a new user, you will just have to update the ssh config to add the key for the new user. BTW: the authorized keys file mentioned is usually in /home/username/.ssh/ (or for root /root/.ssh). See 'man authorized_keys'

Comment: What I'm thinking is, I already disabled ssh root access and I use the single account where I place the ssh-key, what if anybody deletes .ssh directory? how would I individually connect to server if somebody deletes the key file as we disable password logins...

Comment: You need to back it up like other important data. However, removing a hidden dot-folder like .ssh accidentally is quite unlikely. Of course, you could run a regular cron-script to check the health of all the users keys and restore them if need be.

Comment: @Egil: I liked your last comment and it's what called technique. I've no much idea of cloud server, and I think I'll have last option,  that is to access clouds directly in the browser of cloud provider's site if something goes wrong like we access a VM. Is it?

Comment: Many providers give you access to the console of your vm through some sort of managing interface, but it's best to check with your provider to be sure.